# Função if com números decimais

Tags: javascript, funções, formulário, if, else

sou designer e aventureiro em programação e eventualmente adapto alguns códigos em projetos. Estou com uma situação aqui que não consegui resolver sozinho. O seguinte código analisa o valor informado pelo usuário no formulário e, se o número informado estiver dentro de um dos intervalos da função, o script dá uma resposta:

```
function analisar_valor() {
    var info_form = parseInt(document.getElementById("info_form").value);

    var resposta = info_form;
    console.log(resposta);

    if(resposta < 0.005){
      document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = '<p>resposta 1</p>';
    }else if(resposta >= 0.005 && resposta <= 0.499){
      document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = '<p>resposta 2</p>';
    }else if(resposta >= 0.5 && resposta <= 2.999){
      document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = '<p>resposta 3</p>';
    }else if(resposta >= 3 && resposta <= 9.999){
      document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = '<p>resposta 4</p>';
    }else if(resposta >= 10 && resposta <= 50){
      document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = '<p>resposta 5</p>';
    }else if(resposta > 50){
      document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = '<p>resposta 6</p>';
    }
}
```

O problema é que a 1ª primeira resposta do "elseif" (resposta 2) não retorna pq ele não está interpretando números decimais. Qualquer valor decimal informado dá a resposta do "if", e depois a partir do valor "1" ele dá a resposta 3.

De que maneira posso fazer com que ele considere números decimais? Achei algo sobre parseFloat, mas não sei como inserir na função.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na primeira linha da função troque o [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) por [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Comment: Acrescentando: ao usar o `parseInt()` o valor é convertido para inteiro, caso o valor em questão seja um número decimal, será arredondado para baixo. O `parseFloat()` converte a um tipo float, que suporta valores decimais.

Comment: Caraca, perfeito, @rLinhares. Não tinha me atentado a esse parseInt. Resolveu, bingo! Obrigado!

Comment: massa!! mas a resposta foi dada por wensiso.. só editei pra botar as referências dos métodos pra você dar uma olhada ;)